# Php должен отображать все полученные запросы

Tags: php

Доброе утро,т.к я еще новичок в php,то мне сложновато понять,как это сделать.
Надо чтобы сайт exaple.com/request.php - отображал все запросы посланные на него.
[image: Примерно такие запросы,он должен отображать]

Comment: Выводить в ответе содержимое запроса?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/122343/

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю можно так:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```